# Why belongsToMany returns null in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a belongsToMany relationship, where I need to list products and right after the name of the same, the relationship is made between 3 tables, order, description and order_product. 
[image]

As you can realize the field appears empty.

This is my belongsToMany relation:

**Description Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Order;

class Description extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_product_description';
    protected $primaryKey = 'erp_productid';
    protected $fillable = ['erp_name'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'erp_productid','erp_productid');
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'erp_order_product', 'erp_productid', 'erp_createdid');
    }
}
```

**Order Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_order';
    protected $fillable = ['erp_createdid'];

    public function description()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Description', 'erp_order_product', 'erp_createdid', 'erp_productid');
    }
}
```

I used the Laravel 'DebugBar' plugin to see which query is running and returned this:

```
select `erp_product_description`.*, `erp_order_product`.`erp_createdid` as `pivot_erp_createdid`, `erp_order_product`.`erp_productid` as `pivot_erp_productid` from `erp_product_description` inner join `erp_order_product` on `erp_product_description`.`erp_productid` = `erp_order_product`.`erp_productid` where `erp_order_product`.`erp_createdid` is null
```

Why my query received null in value? Any suggestion?

Comment: You are not defining the belongs to many properly... for example this would be a properly defined belongsToMany method: `return $this->belongsToMany(Description::class);` Watch the tutorial on laracasts Laravel from scratch. it's free

Comment: I believe you have confused, the two ways to reference the class work, both 'App \ Description' and Description :: class, as for Laracast, I have already watched the video lessons, but my problem is more specific, I already have some belongsToMany relationships Implemented in my system, only this one has a problem.

Comment: Hi @ViniciusRosa, Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hi @brunocascio, I changed the logic, I put a INNER JOIN in my controller to get this values, in my case that worked perfectly! You have a similar problem? The problem is the compare with VARCHAR type ID, Laravel don't work good with that cases.

Comment: Install "Laravel Debugbar" in your application, click in queries and put this query in a Workbench, is the best way to find this errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I had a `null` problem in a scope function. Cheers